# Sort a file broken into sections by (DOW MON DD YY) date in each section's header

Tags: linux, sorting, uniq

I have a file that has repetitive entries .Entry entry starts with date , a blank line separates these two entries .How do I use sort command or uniq comand to sort the dates :

```
* Mon Jan 29 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Some fixes to init scripts

* Wed Jan 17 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Add missing man pages, fix up init script (Bug #17676)
- Can be patched in for future release.


* Thu Feb 1 2001 Trond Eivind Glomsrød <teg@mail.com>
- Fix check for ipchains
```

I used the sort command like:

```
sort -n -t" " -k5 -k3M -k4
```

but it does not captures the lines after the date , I need to sort the date+contentforthatdate.

Comment: I think a solution could go through transforming the \n before any line not starting with * into another character, say \t (if your text doesn't already contain tabs), then using sort as described, which will sort on the date followed by its tabified text content (since that will now have become one group in one long line), finally after sort turn the tabs back again into newlines.

Comment: You won't be able to accomplish this easily with simple commands, some programming will be required. Awk should suffice, if you're more comfortable with python or perl, use those .... for one there's the paragraph format (then there's the position and format of the date field.

Comment: You appear to be trying to sort changelog entries in a `.spec` file?

Comment: David ... you are right.

Comment: Why does the question specify that you want an answer that uses `sort` or `uniq`, when you're clearly really willing to accept answers that use other tools (perl, awk, etc)? If you don't have a compelling reason for a restriction, you'll get a wider range of answers if you leave it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on @jchevali's comment - one just needs to find a printable character that both awk and tr can handle gracefully that's not in the text to be processed:

```
awk '/^*/{printf "%s ^",$0} /^-/{printf "%s ^",$0} /^[ \t]*$/{printf "\n"}' paras | sort -n -t" " -k5 -k3M -k4  | tr '^' '\n'

* Wed Jan 17 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com> 
- Add missing man pages, fix up init script (Bug #17676) 
- Can be patched in for future release. 

* Mon Jan 29 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com> 
- Some fixes to init scripts 

* Thu Feb 1 2001 Trond Eivind Glomsrød <teg@mail.com> 
- Fix check for ipchains
```

Comment: Good craft. You did this better than I could myself.

Comment: Had no idea you could use sort to sort by month abbreviations (`-M`). Neat.

Comment: thanks Tink it works . Could you suggest if it`s a reverse sort how to achieve it , regrets as I did nt mention in the question . sort -r is not working.

Comment: Just change the sort to look like this `sort -t" " -k5nr -k3Mr -k4nr ` ... @ParasPandey

Answer (score 1):

With Perl also you can do it,

```
> cat paras.txt
* Mon Jan 29 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Some fixes to init scripts

* Wed Jan 17 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Add missing man pages, fix up init script (Bug #17676)
- Can be patched in for future release.


* Thu Feb 1 2001 Trond Eivind Glomsrød <teg@mail.com>
- Fix check for ipchains
> perl -lne ' $_=/^\*/?$_:/^-/?"!$_":"\n"; printf("%s",$_);END{print} ' paras.txt | sort -n -t" " -k5 -k3M -k4  | tr '!' '\n' | sed 's/^\*/\n*/g'


* Wed Jan 17 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Add missing man pages, fix up init script (Bug #17676)
- Can be patched in for future release.

* Mon Jan 29 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Some fixes to init scripts

* Thu Feb 1 2001 Trond Eivind Glomsrød <teg@mail.com>
- Fix check for ipchains
>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Input** (as describe in the question there are some double empty lines) :

```
cat input
* Mon Jan 29 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Some fixes to init scripts

* Wed Jan 17 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Add missing man pages, fix up init script (Bug #17676)
- Can be patched in for future release.


* Thu Feb 1 2001 Trond Eivind Glomsrød <teg@mail.com>
- Fix check for ipchains
```

**Command:**

```
cat -s input | awk '!/^$/{printf $0;next}{print}' | sort -n -t" " -k5 -k3M -k4 | sed 's/- /\n- /g;s/$/\n/'
```

**Output:**

```
cat -s input | awk '!/^$/{printf $0;next}{print}' | sort -n -t" " -k5 -k3M -k4 | sed 's/- /\n- /g;s/$/\n/'
* Wed Jan 17 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Add missing man pages, fix up init script (Bug #17676)
- Can be patched in for future release.

* Mon Jan 29 2001 Bernhard Rosenkraenzer <bero@mail.com>
- Some fixes to init scripts

* Thu Feb 1 2001 Trond Eivind Glomsrød <teg@mail.com>
- Fix check for ipchains
```

(note that the empty double lines have been removed)

**Explanations:**

- `cat -s input` will remove the successive empty lines (if you do not have those in your input file you can remove this part of the command)
- `awk '!/^$/{printf $0;next}{print}'` will fold the lines without adding extra characters by simply printing the line without `\n` when the line is not empty and when it is empty it will only add a `EOL` char
- `sort -n -t" " -k5 -k3M -k4` your sorting operation
- `sed 's/- /\n- /g;s/$/\n/'` to separate the lines as they were before the `awk` by adding `\n` before the patterns starting with `-` and adding an `\n` at the end of each line to recreate the empty lines.